# Cannot access parent class variable from child class in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two classes, a parent class and a child class that inherits from the parent class. When initializing the child class I call the constructor of the parent class with the `super()` keyword. Then I attempt to access the parent class variable in a child method. However, when I attempt to do this I receive this error: `Cannot read property 'undefined'`. Why is the variable undefined? Does the constructor not work as I expected it to?

```js
    class Book {
      constructor(title, author, chapters) {
        this.title = title; //string
        this.author = author; //string
        this.chapters = chapters; //array of strings
      }
      getTitle() {
        return this.title;
      }
      getAuthor() {
        return this.author;
      }
    }
    class Chapter extends Book {
      constructor(title, author, chapters, numberPages, subject, time, chapterIndex) {
        super(title, author, chapters);
        this.numberPages = numberPages;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.time = time;
        this.chapterIndex = chapterIndex;
      }
      getChapterText() {
        return this.chapters[this.chapterIndex];
      }
    }

    var chapterOne = new Chapter("title", "author", ["lorem ipsum...", "lorem ipsum...", "lorem ipsum..."], 42, "about lorem ipsum", "3:01", 0); //book_object is an array of everything the chapter constructor needs
    console.log(chapterOne.getChapterText());
```

I've also tried using `super.chapters` to access the parent class variable, but I just got this error: `unexpected keyword super`.

**Update**

Maybe using `${book_object}` made my question too confusing. This javascript is running as JSP (java server page). Therefore it's being compiled before being served. I updated my question to reduce confusion.

**Update 2**

```js
    class Book {
      constructor(title, author, chapters) {
        this.title = title; //string
        this.author = author; //string
        this.chapters = chapters; //array of strings
      }
      getTitle() {
        return this.title;
      }
      getAuthor() {
        return this.author;
      }
    }
    class Chapter extends Book {
      constructor(title, author, chapters, numberPages, subject, time, chapterIndex) {
        super(title, author, chapters);
        this.numberPages = numberPages;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.time = time;
        this.currentChapter = this.getChapterText(); //I forgot to include this line in my original question.
        this.chapterIndex = chapterIndex;
      }
      getChapterText() {
        return this.chapters[this.chapterIndex];
      }
    }

    var chapterOne = new Chapter("title", "author", ["lorem ipsum...", "lorem ipsum...", "lorem ipsum..."], 42, "about lorem ipsum", "3:01", 0); //book_object is an array of everything the chapter constructor needs
    console.log(chapterOne.currentChapter);
```

I just realized that in my actual code (the code in this question is based on my actual code) I was calling my child class method in my child class constructor, and in that method I was trying to access my parent class variable. Here is a snippet of that. Turns out my issue was this all along. Would someone care to explain why this happens?

Comment: Why is `Chapter` a subclass of `Book`? A book can contain multiple chapters, so a chapter is not a kind of book.

Comment: When you call `new Chapter()` you don't provide the `chapters` argument, so it's undefined. So `this.chapters = chapters` sets it to `undefined`. The problem has nothing to do with accessing parent properties.

Comment: The way you've set this up, a Chapter is also a Book , just a special kind of book. There is no parent here to access.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, but it's not the case. The semantic does not matter, and, if you consider a book made by books, a chapter can sure be an book too.

Comment: What is `${book_object}`? That's not valid syntax for a variable. It looks like the syntax used in template literals.

Comment: @Michael with your latest code, it's logging out 'lorem Ipsum...'. So is the problem solved?

Comment: It's working for you?? Hmm. I made this question as a dumbed down version of the code I'm actually using. Maybe I dumbed it down so much that I ended up fixing my problem.

Comment: I just realized that I was calling my function `getChapterText` in my constructor on my actual code. I updated this question to better reflect that.

Comment: In your latest code, you're calling getChapterText before you set this.chapterIndex.  getChapterText relies on this.chapterIndex. Swap the order of those two lines.

Comment: Okay, I just tried that, and it worked. But it's not working for my actual code. Therefor my issue must not be in my understanding of how classes work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I finally found my issue with my main code. I had the dumbest typo in my parent class constructor. It was missing the 's'. So when I was initializing my class, the parent class constructor wasn't setting the variables appropriately. Jeez I can't believe this problem took me a day to solve.

Answer (score 1):

> var chapterOne = new Chapter(${book_object}); //book_object is an array of everything the chapter constructor needs

The constructor you've defined expects a comma separate sequence of title, author, chapters, numberPages, etc. As long as you pass that in, things will work. But if you're passing in an object or array like you describe, then that's just a single parameter, which will be the "title" parameter in the constructor. The remaining parameters are undefined.

So either change your constructor to expect the object you're passing in, or change the way you call the constructor

```
const chapterOne = new Chapter('some title', 'some author', ['chapter1', 'chapter2'], 42, /*etc*/);
```

If ${book_object} is an actual array, which happens to have the parameters in the right order, you could use the spread operator to turn it into the list of arguments:

```
const bookArray = [
  'some title', 
  'some author', 
  ['chapter1', 'chapter'2],
  42
  // etc
]
const chapterOne = new Chapter(...bookArray);
```

Comment: Maybe using `${book_object}` made my question too confusing. This javascript is running as JSP (java server page). Therefore it's being compiled before being served. I updated my question to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If `book_object` is an array of the parameters needed by the contructor, you need to spread it. The correct syntax is `...variable`, not `${variable}`.

```
var chapterOne = new Chapter(...book_object)
```